# Why does Prolog returns true to this query

Tags: prolog

Prolog newbie here.
I have this program:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).

path(X,X).
path(X,Y):- edge(X,Z),path(Z,Y).
```

I can't understand why Prolog returns true to this query:

`path(a,c)`

Comment: Why do you expect the query to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns `true` because the prolog engine can prove your query.

You can imagine the prolog engine doing this when you query `path(a,c)`:

- first clause of `path/2` fails because it cannot unify `X` with `a` and `c` at the same time
- so it enters the second clause where `X` gets unified with `a` and `Y` with `c`, then it calls `edge(a, Z)`.
- As there is a fact `edge(a,b)`, `Z` gets unified with `b`. Then it tries to prove `path(b, c)`
- The first clause for `path/2` fails again because it cannot unify `X` with `b` and `c` at the same time
- so it enters the second clause where `X` gets unified with `b` and `Y` with `c`, then it calls `edge(b, Z)`. Note that this variables (`X`, `Y`, `Z` are not the same variables as in the first call to path). Then it tries to prove `path(c, c)`
- Now the first clause for path/2 succeeds as it unifies `X` with `c` and there are no further goals.
- The previous calls to path/2 also succeed because they were at the final goal in each clause.